# Listview not showing flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have listview with some image and details,the listview shows with dummy data it's working fine but if i tried to call API and initialized value insteavd of dummy data but the listview not even shows up in screen.
Also I am getting data from API upto `var restaurants = value['restaurants'][0];` but i cannot access the data to listview,There is no error messages,no problems in flutter doctor
API Call

```
Future<String> getRestaurantList() async {
    ProgressDialog dialog = CustomDialogs().showLoadingProgressDialog(context);

    var response = await http.post(
      Urls.HOME_RESTAURANTS,
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: json.encode({
        "line1": "lat_11.2717278\$75.7775994",
        "category": "all",
        "term": "null",
      }),
    );
    Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      dialog.dismissProgressDialog(context);
      try {
        print("response " + response.body.toString());
        var message = value['msg'];
        var rescount = value['count'];
        if (message == "Exist") {
          var restaurants = value['restaurants'][0];
          for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
            var data = restaurants[i];
            print("response"+ data);
            HomeRestauarantList.add(HomeRestauarantModel.fromJson(data));
          }

        } else {
          final snackBar = SnackBar(
              content: Text("No Restaurants Available in the Location"));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        e.toString();
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  }
```

View

```
  Widget restList = Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          child: ListView.separated(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  const Divider(),
              itemCount: HomeRestauarantList.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                HomeRestauarantModel data = HomeRestauarantList[index];
                return Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => RestaurantScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 0,
                              child: Image.network(
                                data.logo,
                                height: 80,
                                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                              ),

                              //radius: 52.5,
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1,
                              child: Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                                child: Row(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      flex: 0,
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                            child: Text(
                                              data.name,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 15,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                            child: Text(
                                              data.tag_line,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                color: Colors.grey,
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5),
                                            child: Text(
                                              "20% Offer above ₹130",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 12,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                color: const Color(0xFFCBB032),
                                              ),
                                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                            ),
                                          ),

                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Model

```
class HomeRestauarantModel {
  String res_id;
  String name;
  String logo;
  String status;
  String tag_line;
  String min_prepration_time;

  HomeRestauarantModel({
    this.res_id,
    this.name,
    this.logo,
    this.status,
    this.tag_line,
    this.min_prepration_time,
  });

  HomeRestauarantModel.fromJson(json)
      : res_id = json['res_id'].toString(),
        name = json['name'],
        logo = json['logo'].toString(),
        status = json['status'].toString(),
        tag_line = json['tag_line'].toString(),
        min_prepration_time = json['min_prepration_time'].toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: The ListView has render when getRestaurantList() isn't fisnished. You should be user FutureBuilder or call setState() when getRestaurantList() complete!

Comment: Can you help me with code please..? @Trần Nhật Nam Lê

Answer (score 0):

When ListView is built, there is no data in 'HomeRestauarantList'. So when 'HomeRestauarantList' is changed, need to widget rebuild using setState().

Or wait build for 'HomeRestauarantList' is updated using 'FuretureBuilder'.
Or look around about  Bloc, Provider pattern.

Comment: where is the call of 'getRestaurantList'?
Would you change that code like this? 'setState(() async { await getRestaurantList(); })'

Comment: i have called like this `  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getRestaurantList();
    
  }`

Comment: i tried with this causes error `setState() callback argument returned a Future.` @KuKu

Comment: Or how about you use FutureBuilder? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: yes i did all can see loading text i am giving even if the data is loaded,it's same @KuKu